# How can I add data of one record in access through two queries?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, if-statement

```
Dim todaydate As String = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now)
        Dim expdate As String = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", dtpexpdate.Value)
        Dim ordersql As String
        ordersql = "Insert into SalesTable([BookID],[Username],[Phone No],[Address],[Payment method],[SaleDate]) Values(?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(ordersql, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookID", lbid.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtusernm.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone No", txtphone.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtaddr.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payment method", cbpaymeth.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SaleDate", todaydate)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("1st Done!")

        Dim order2sql As String
        order2sql = "Insert into SalesTable([Payment status],[Card No],[Expiry Date]) Values(?,?,?) Where BookID='" & lbid.Text & "'AND Username='" & txtusernm.Text & "'"

        If cbpaymeth.Text Like "Cash-on-Delivery" Then
            Dim cmd2 As New OleDbCommand(order2sql, conn)
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payment status", False)
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Card No", 0)
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Expiry Date", "")
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("2nd Do-o-one")
        Else
            Dim cmd2 As New OleDbCommand(order2sql, conn)
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payment status", True)
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Card No", txtcardno.Text)
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Expiry Date", expdate)
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("2nd Done")
        End If

        Dim quansql As String
        quansql = "Update BooksTable Set Quantity = Quantity-1 Where [BookID]= '" & lbid.Text & "'"
        Dim cm As New OleDbCommand(quansql, conn)
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()
        MsgBox("Your Order has been Placed", vbExclamation)
```

When I select 'Cash-on-delivery' in the combobox for the payment method value and click the button, the ordersql query command is executed successfully with its parameters but the 1st set of code for the if condition shows an error **"Query input must contain at least one table or query"** at the cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery() line.

When I select 'Credit/Debit Card', nothing happens at all no matter how many times I click the button.

Can anyone show me how to add the data of one record through two queries using a simple code?

Comment: You don't have a `WHERE` clause on an `INSERT` statement. The point of a `WHERE` clause is to filter existing rows to determine which to operate on. An `INSERT` statement doesn't operate on existing rows so how could a `WHERE` clause make sense? Did you actually mean to `UPDATE` the record you just inserted?

Comment: @jmcilhinney. That's right. I wanted to update the record I just inserted. But I have a Where clause in the second insert command which specifies the two unique fields that have been inserted by the first insert command. `order2sql = "Insert into SalesTable([Payment status],[Card No],[Expiry Date]) Values(?,?,?) Where BookID='" & lbid.Text & "'AND Username='" & txtusernm.Text & "'"`

Comment: Also, never handle dates as text, always as _DateTime_.

Comment: @Gustav. I was getting Data-type-mismatch errors all the time even though I had the data type for date in access as DateTime and was returning the value in the form as a date. So I took the string way for date.

Comment: That's no way to take, it's a dead end. It may even cause serious trouble. Browse for how to insert DateTime values.

Comment: @aromazing AddWithValue can cause problems because it tries to guess the data type. Add the parameters like this: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Payment method", OleDbType.VarChar, 26).Value = cbpaymeth.Text` (change the oledbtype to be what it is in the DB and the size `26` to be as declared in the DB), and `cmd.Parameters.Add("@SaleDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.UtcNow`.

Comment: *"I wanted to update the record I just inserted"*. Did you read what you just wrote? You say yourself that you want to update, so why are you using an `INSERT` statement? Not surprisingly, you use an `UPDATE` statement to update.

Comment: @halfer. I understand.

Comment: @jmcilhinney. I realised it immediately after I wrote it like that. Silly me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert all the data in one go. Instead of adding the parameters depending on the value of something, add the parameters and set their values depending on that something.

Like this:

```
Dim todaydate As DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow
Dim expdate As DateTime = dtpexpdate.Value

Dim ordersql As String = "INSERT INTO SalesTable([BookID], [Username], [Phone No], [Address], [Payment method], [SaleDate], [Payment status], [Card No], [Expiry Date]) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

Using conn As New OleDbConnection("your connection string"),
        cmd As New OleDbCommand(ordersql, conn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@BookID", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarWChar, .Size = 99, .Value = lbid.Text})
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Username", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarWChar, .Size = 255, .Value = txtusernm.Text})
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Phone No", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar, .Size = 24, .Value = txtphone.Text})
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Address", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar, .Size = 24, .Value = txtaddr.Text})
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Payment method", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar, .Size = 24, .Value = cbpaymeth.Text})
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@SaleDate", .OleDbType = OleDbType.Date, .Value = todaydate})

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Payment status", .OleDbType = OleDbType.Boolean})
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Card No", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar, .Size = 16})
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Expiry Date", .OleDbType = OleDbType.Date})

    If cbpaymeth.Text.Equals("Cash-on-Delivery", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
        cmd.Parameters("@Payment status").Value = False
        cmd.Parameters("@Payment status").Value = DBNull.Value
        cmd.Parameters("@Expiry Date").Value = DBNull.Value
    Else
        cmd.Parameters("@Payment status").Value = True
        cmd.Parameters("@Payment status").Value = txtcardno.Text
        cmd.Parameters("@Expiry Date").Value = expdate
    End If

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox("1st Done!")

End Using

Dim quansql As String = "UPDATE BooksTable SET [Quantity] = [Quantity] - 1 WHERE [BookID] = ?"

Using conn As New OleDbConnection("your connection string"),
        cmd As New OleDbCommand(quansql, conn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@BookID", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarWChar, .Size = 48, .Value = lbid.Text})

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Using

MessageBox.Show("Your order has been placed", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

You need to change the values of each `.OleDbType` and `.Size` to match the declarations in the database - I just guessed.

You might want to *not* store credit card information because storing that leaves you liable for a lot of money if things go wrong.

Comment: *"You might want to not store credit card information because storing that leaves you liable for a lot of money if things go wrong"* Would it be okay if I don't include Card No and Expiry Date in the billing form, then? That would save me a lot of trouble.

Comment: If it uses some sort of third-party payment system, it might be useful to store the transaction reference, but yes, try hard to avoid storing CC information.

Comment: I tried the solution using the credit card info. It's the same problem. Cash-on-Delivery does okay, but credit/debit card does nothing when I click the button. ETA: it seems as if the code breaks off somewhere whenever I choose Credit/Debit Card option.

Comment: If `cbpaymeth` is a CheckBox, then it should be `If cbpaymeth.Checked Then` instead of checking its .Text property.

Comment: No. It's a ComboBox.

Comment: @aromazing: if your card processor learns that you are storing card numbers, in general they will (and should) stop their service to you. Please check with them to see what the best practice is for your situation.

Comment: @halfer. I'll see to that. Thanks.